# How does recursion work in this code and not terminate after the if condition is not satisfied?

Tags: c++, recursion

Can someone please explain to me how this prints `10 9 8 7...1` and not just `10`?

`cout<<b[x]<<endl;` is inside `if(x<y)`, so how come does it not terminate after x reaches 9, making it print 10 only?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void someFunction(int[], int, int);

int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int value=10;
    someFunction(a,0,value);
    return 0;
}

void someFunction(int b[], int x, int y){
    if(x<y){
        someFunction(b,x+1,y);
        cout<<b[x]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's confusing me is that how does it print from 10 to 1 and not just 10?

Comment: The function does not terminate after the condition fail. It `returns`. When it returns it goes back to where it was called.

Comment: When it returns it goes back to where it was called from--and there's code after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try thinking of this in terms of code substituation.

At each point that `someFunction()` is called swap in the actual code of the function.

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void someFunction(int[], int, int);

int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int value=10;
    someFunction(a,0,value);
    return 0;
}

void someFunction(int b[], int x, int y){
    if(x<y){
        someFunction(b,x+1,y);
        cout<<b[x]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Lets look at the one line in main that matters:

```
someFunction(a,0,10);
```

Step 1: Replace this by the function body (replacing the variables with the actual paramters)

```
if(0<10){
    someFunction(a,1,10);
    cout<<a[0]<<endl;
}
```

Step 2: That if statement is always true so lets remove it:

```
someFunction(a,1,10);
cout<<a[0]<<endl;
```

Repeat Steps 1

```
if(1<10){
    someFunction(a,2,10);
    cout<<a[1]<<endl;
}
cout<<a[0]<<endl;
```

Repeat Steps 2

```
someFunction(a,2,10);
cout<<a[1]<<endl;
cout<<a[0]<<endl;
```

We still have a call to `someFunction()` so lets repeat again:

```
if(2<10){
    someFunction(a,3,10);
    cout<<a[2]<<endl;
}
cout<<a[1]<<endl;
cout<<a[0]<<endl;
```

And:

```
someFunction(a,3,10);
cout<<a[2]<<endl;
cout<<a[1]<<endl;
cout<<a[0]<<endl;
```

OK. You see the pattern. This repeats until you get to fail condition.

```
someFunction(a,10,10);
cout<<a[9]<<endl;
cout<<a[8]<<endl;
cout<<a[7]<<endl;
cout<<a[6]<<endl;
cout<<a[5]<<endl;
cout<<a[4]<<endl;
cout<<a[3]<<endl;
cout<<a[2]<<endl;
cout<<a[1]<<endl;
cout<<a[0]<<endl;
```

Now if we replace that last call

```
if(10<10){
    someFunction(a,11,10);
    cout<<a[10]<<endl;
}
cout<<a[9]<<endl;
cout<<a[8]<<endl;
cout<<a[7]<<endl;
cout<<a[6]<<endl;
cout<<a[5]<<endl;
cout<<a[4]<<endl;
cout<<a[3]<<endl;
cout<<a[2]<<endl;
cout<<a[1]<<endl;
cout<<a[0]<<endl;
```

This time we see that the condition is false. So we can remove it and the code.

```
cout<<a[9]<<endl;
cout<<a[8]<<endl;
cout<<a[7]<<endl;
cout<<a[6]<<endl;
cout<<a[5]<<endl;
cout<<a[4]<<endl;
cout<<a[3]<<endl;
cout<<a[2]<<endl;
cout<<a[1]<<endl;
cout<<a[0]<<endl;
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you so much
You made it really easy to understand.. I've been trying for two hours